# aws-sdk (node) S3 NoSuchKey Error with keys returned by listObjectsV2

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I have an [AWS lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/it/lambda/) which is triggered by an 
[SNS queue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/welcome.html). The lambda uses node 10.x as engine and [aws-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk), when triggered it should collect a list of objects from [S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/gsg/GetStartedWithS3.html) and do some processing. All these objects have a name with a common prefix (which is extracted from the SNS event). I'am using the [listObjectsV2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjectsV2-property) to get all the objects keys from the S3 bucket with the same prefix (assumes all objects metadata can be retrieved in one call) and then [getObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getObject-property) to construct promises to retrieve objects data.
The relevant code is the following:

```
const params = {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Prefix: prefix,
    MaxKeys: maxKeys,
};

const objectsListResponse = await s3.listObjectsV2(params).promise();

const promises = objectsListResponse.Contents.map(o => s3.getObject({
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Key: o.Key,
}).promise());

const results = await Promise.all(promises);
```

My problem is that sometimes (not always) I got a `NoSuchKey: The specified key does not exist` error. My assumption was that all the keys included in the `listObjectsV2` response are valid, but this does not seem always the case. Anyone has any advice or workaround for this issue?

NB: all objects stored on S3 bucket have valid key names without special characters

Comment: don't see anything wrong with the code. The only thing comes to my mind is number of objects retruned from list objects call. If the number is lest say 1000, you will open 1000 promises in parallel from your lambda function to fetch the objects in memory, Although in your case this shouldn't be a problem but worth trying the same code which return less number of object list.

Comment: Space is also a special character, confusingly provided in the event notification as `+`.